# How to sort before aggregation in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, aggregation

I have an Elasticsearch index structured like this

```json
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "content": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields":{
                    "keyword":{
                        "type":"keyword",
                        "ignore_above":20
                    }
                }
            },
            "result_nums":{
                "type":"integer"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and all documents in the index like this

```json
{
  "content": "this",
  "result_nums": 40
},
{
  "content": "this",
  "result_nums": 40
},
{
  "content": "that",
  "result_nums": 40
},
{
  "content": "what",
  "result_nums": 50
},
{
  "content": "what",
  "result_nums": 50
},
{
  "content": "but",
  "result_nums": 100
},
{
  "content": "like",
  "result_nums": 20
}
```

I need to get the data, sorting by `result_nums` `DESC` and removing duplicate "content". For example, I used the query like this to get the first two data

```json
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "content": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "content.keyword",
                "size": 2
            },
            "aggs": {
                "res_nums": {
                    "avg": {
                        "field": "result_nums"
                    }
                },
                "res_sort": {
                    "bucket_sort": {
                        "sort": [
                            {
                                "res_nums": "desc"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The data I expect to get is

```json
                {
                    "key": "but",
                    "doc_count": 1,
                    "res_nums": {
                        "value": 100.0
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "what",
                    "doc_count": 2,
                    "res_nums": {
                        "value": 50.0
                    }
                }
```

But what I actually get is

```
                {
                    "key": "what",
                    "doc_count": 2,
                    "res_nums": {
                        "value": 50.0
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "this",
                    "doc_count": 2,
                    "res_nums": {
                        "value": 40.0
                    }
                }
```

so I think es needs to be sorted before aggregation, because now it will only be sorted after aggregation, so I got results that did not match expectations.

I tried to use `sort` before aggregation but no effect

```
{
"size": 0,
    "sort": [
        {
            "result_nums": "desc"
        }
    ],
    "aggs": {
    ...
    }
...
}
```

So how to do sort before aggregation?

Comment: Your match query is already sorted by score before aggregation is applied. What is a good use case for this?

Comment: Hello, I have just added the content of my question,could you help me take a look? thank you very much.

Comment: @dengbuqi where is the document `"content": "what"`, and how you are getting `what` in your expected result ?

Comment: sorry, there are some errors in the content of my question, now I have corrected it. In addition, the data I give examples are just to describe the situation I met. If you use my data, you may not get the same results as me.

Comment: Yes @dengbuqi when I am using your updated data, with the same search query that you gave in the question above, I am getting the result that you expect to get

Comment: Ok, now I have corrected it, may be you can get the result I do not expect. If you still do not have my problem, it may be related to the order in which the document was inserted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [max aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-max-aggregation.html) along with [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) to get the data, sorting by `result_nums` DESC and removing duplicate "content"

Adding a working example

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "content": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "content.keyword",
        "order": {
          "max_num": "desc"
        },
        "size":2
      },
      "aggs": {
        "max_num": {
          "max": {
            "field": "result_nums"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"aggregations": {
    "content": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 4,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "but",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "max_num": {
            "value": 100.0
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "what",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "max_num": {
            "value": 50.0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Amazing! this is what I want, thank you very much!